# Response time of web requests

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt

We have a web application which is implemented in 3 tier architecture using J2EE stack. The application is mainly fetching the result set from the database based on search criteria and our stack uses GWT, EJB3.0 hibernate and a RDBMS.

We have our search logic/queries  in stateless session beans. The servlets/controller invoke these stateless session beans to fetch the search results. Since we are using GWT as UI framework, so we use POJO/models to  render on UI widget like table/grids etc.

Our model objects are  way too heavy , since contains lot of business information in order to show in UI and it has to run  array of queries, permissions etc.  Due to this, the searches are taking pretty long. 
In an average if  each model generation is taking 1 sec, it takes around 15 secs to generate 15 models which is our pagination limit on UI.

I want to optimize the model generation time,I can think of running model generation in a thread  but how do I maintain the order of the results from DB/WS.
Could you suggest what are all the best possible way to improve the response time  ?

Pseudocode on SLSB looks like below.

```
search(criteria,paging properties){
Get PRIMARY keys by running the query based on search criteria from DB/WS
for each key/id  build the model //This is taking too long as it's synchronous 
return list of models in sorting order back to controller with paging properties

}
```

Comment: What are you running to do your searches?  Have you tried the EXPLAIN command?  Do you have indexes where needed?  How long is "pretty long"?  What have you profiled?

Comment: Regarding the time it is taking to build the model. What does it do?
Do you really need all the fields in the model to be initialized?
Can you select only the fields necessary for the UI and populate a DTO object from the query that can be used to build the view?

Comment: OK. Building models  dependents on other session beans and bunch of queries. We do have indexes on the tables  but still it takes  1 sec to run whole bunch of queries  which is fine.  Since I want  togenerate 20 such models hence it takes more time. As am just looping through each model in synchronous way. How can we achieve concurrency and maintain the order . We need all the fields on the model.